# How do I adjust the position of my chart to take up the whole chart area?

Tags: c#, mschart

I was looking at [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988827/asp-net-ms-chart-control-pie-chart-remove-unwanted-padding) and trying to relate to my current situation.  I have a line bar chart with too much whitespace around the chart area.  Can the position property be used to reduce this white space?

[image: my chart]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the suggestion from the post you linked:

> Then you need IsMarginVisible = false to prevent the margin on the left and the right.

If that didn't help you can try the suggestion from [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12985210/107177):

> Try playing with the InnerPlotPosition settings:
>
> `chart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.X = 0;`