# MS Chart how to remove these unwanted circles when type is spine

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart

[image]

I am using MSChart and type is spine. I generated a graph and its working.But there is some issue happens and graph marked as white. How can i fix that extra items. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to write css?

Comment: no. Its create a image and image is renderd .`<img id="chrtReports" src="/Reports/ChartImg.axd?i=chart_caf70d765601474f9e480850b22ef284_0.png&amp;g=b9f5f2e9a3424a108b1d7878d7a6151c" alt="" style="height:600px;width:900px;border-width:0px;">`

Comment: Can you please check this URL, this is similar of your question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988827/asp-net-ms-chart-control-pie-chart-remove-unwanted-padding

Comment: I think it may be due to the data points. I am validating the datapoints.

Comment: Yes. Splines tend to do that when the values are changing too fast for the spline curve to follow.. usually adding a few points around the spots of the fast change can help, but with datapoints that may be a problem. maybe you have to give up on splines and go for another charttype i.e. line..